Is there a $b$ for every $a$, such that the decimal representation of $b^b$ contains $a$?

Is there a $b$ for every $a$, such that the decimal representation of $b^b$ contains $a$?
($a$ and $b$ are positive integers)

This is a question my friend asked recently.
I've checked that there is indeed such a $b$ $(\le889)$ for every $a  \le 10^5$.
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to attack this problem. 
An internet search didn't yield anything either.
Additionally, is this true for every base?

Since the "middle" digits of $b^b$ with some random large $b$ should be more or less random , I guess we can always find a suitable $b$ , in fact probably some $b$ covering all $a$ with at most $k$ digits.

@Peter: so prove it!

My program agrees with yours up to $a=10^5$; and I can report that there is such a $b\le 3172$ for every $a\le 10^6$.

...and there is a $b\le 9603$ for every $a\le 10^7$. (The last holdout was $a=4961706$.) I think I'll stop there!

@Peter: If in fact we can always find such a $b$ for every $a$, then we can always find some $b$ covering all $k$-digit numbers: just take $a$ to be the concatenation of every single $k$-digit number.

@TonyK: so prove it!

It is well possible that we cannot present a proof. But Tony's computation is enough to convince me.

@Euclid: prove what? I wrote a program to check all values of $a$ up to $10^7$. I can send it to you if you like. (But I'm not going to comment it.)
